# Purchasing UPlay game on Steam

Tags: steam, far-cry-3, drm, ubisoft-connect

I purchased Far Cry 3 on my Steam account, I downloaded the game from Steam and when I ran it I got a key to activate the game on UPlay but, when I run the game I should login to both services.

If I uninstall the game and download it again via UPlay, Will I be able to play it without logging in Steam?

Comment: Assuming it's the same as the last time I tried playing that game then unfortunately no, Steam must be running in order for UPlay to recognise the game as being installed :(

Comment: I mean that I will remove it so, the game is installed via UPlay not Steam.

Comment: With Heroes of might and magic (6 iirc), I could launch it from UPlay without having steam running even if I had bought it on Steam. Ubisoft's games bought on Steam are usually all working with Uplay and Steam is just a front-end service but not the actual one the game uses. The Crew and GTA V(but from Rockstar) works in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At current it is downloaded with steam. If you delete the game, and re download it directly from Uplay, then yes. You should be able to play without steam.

Comment: Afaik no, when you click install in uplay, it launches steam. Removing steam might help tho.